# Transition on star wars hyperspace jump style website animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

The animation works correctly, but once the 5 seconds of the animation have passed, I would like a more effective transition to be performed so that the screen goes white, the main problem is that there is this sharp detachment of the stars and this transition that does not it is pleasing to the eye

I tried to make a scale of colors in order to go from black background to white background without being able to fix the sharp detachment of the stars and the effect that creates the scale of colors

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #animation-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    canvas {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="animation-container">
    <script>
      var stars = [];
var startTime;
var animationDuration = 5; // in seconds

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  fullscreen(true);
  for (var i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
    stars[i] = new Star();
  }
  startTime = millis(); // Record the start time
}

var transitioning = false; // Flag per la transizione
var transitionStartTime; // Ora di inizio della transizione

function cubicEase(t) {
  return t * t * t;
}

function draw() {
  var currentTime = millis() - startTime;
  var normalizedTime = constrain(currentTime / (animationDuration * 1000), 0, 1); // Normalize time between 0 and 1
  var easedTime = cubicEase(normalizedTime); // Apply easing to normalized time

  var speed;

  if (normalizedTime < 1) {
    speed = map(normalizedTime, 0, 1, 0, 50); // Linear speed increase
  } else {
    speed = map(normalizedTime, 1, 0.8, 50, 100); // Speed increase in the last 20% of animation
  }

  background(0);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);

  if (normalizedTime < 1 && currentTime < animationDuration * 5000) {
    for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      stars[i].update(speed);
      stars[i].show();
    }
  } else {
    if (!transitioning && easedTime >= 1) {
      transitioning = true; // Set the transitioning flag
      transitionStartTime = millis(); // Record the transition start time
    }

    // Calculate the time since the start of the transition
    var transitionElapsedTime = millis() - transitionStartTime;

    // Calculate the duration of the transition (e.g., 2 seconds)
    var transitionDuration = 2000; // 2 seconds in milliseconds

    // Calculate the eased time for the transition
    var transitionNormalizedTime = constrain(transitionElapsedTime / transitionDuration, 0, 1);
    var transitionEasedTime = cubicEase(transitionNormalizedTime);

    // Transition from black to white using eased time
    var backgroundColor = lerpColor(color(0), color(255), transitionEasedTime);
    background(backgroundColor);

    if (transitioning && transitionNormalizedTime >= 1) {
      // Animation is over and transition is complete, remove the animation container
      var animationContainer = document.getElementById("animation-container");
      if (animationContainer) {
        animationContainer.parentNode.removeChild(animationContainer);
      }
      noLoop(); // Stop the draw loop
    }
  }
}

function Star() {
  this.x = random(-width, width);
  this.y = random(-height, height);
  this.z = random(width);
  this.pz = this.z;

  this.update = function (speed) {
    this.z = this.z - speed;
    if (this.z < 1) {
      this.z = width;
      this.x = random(-width, width);
      this.y = random(-height, height);
      this.pz = this.z;
    }
  };

  this.show = function () {
    fill(255);
    noStroke();

    var sx = map(this.x / this.z, 0, 1, 0, width);
    var sy = map(this.y / this.z, 0, 1, 0, height);

    var r = map(this.z, 0, width, 16, 0);

    var px = map(this.x / this.pz, 0, 1, 0, width);
    var py = map(this.y / this.pz, 0, 1, 0, height);

    this.pz = this.z;

    stroke(255);
    line(px, py, sx, sy);
  };
}
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```